# Game logic - Add score only once after passing obstacle

Tags: java, logic

I'm creating a game with a score system similar to the one in Flappy Bird.

[if you didn't get it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7f4m.png)

When the player successfully passes the right and left
obstacle I want my score variable to increase by 1. I don't know the logic behind it though.

Right now I have (this is inside a for loop checking every obstacle in an update method):

'over' making sure the score only increases by 1.

```
if (bird.getPosition().y > obstacle.getPosLeft().y) {
  if (!over) {
    over = true;
    score++;
  }
```

and when the obstacle gets off the screen (yes, y is 0 at the bottom, not the top):

```
if (obstacle.getPosLeft().y + Obstacle.OBSTACLE_HEIGHT < 0){
  obstacle.reposition(obstacle.getPosLeft().y + (OBSTACLE_SPACING + Obstacle.OBSTACLE_HEIGHT)* OBSTACLE_COUNT);
  over = false;
}
```

The problem is that you can pass 2 obstacle pairs before the first one gets re-positioned which means that you only get the 2nd point after `reposition()` is called for obstacle 1.

How would you fix this problem?

Comment: What happens if you just `score++` instead of having the `if` statement?

Comment: it just adds score every tick if I'm above any obstacle. I mean, you get lots of points (which is cool and all), but that's not what I wanna do.

Comment: Could you call the reposition right when you pass the obstacle? Since you have already passed the obstacle, you do not care about it anymore, so you can reposition it. Try that.

Comment: Then the obstacle would basically just get deleted because it just repositions to above the screen. I want it to reposition when it leaves the screen giving the illusion that there are many obstacles raining down on the player. It's silly for it to just vanish when the player passes it. Are you with me? Let me know if I don't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, your explanation is clear. How are you getting the obstacle? If there are two of them, do you have two obstacle variables, or merely two instances of an `Obstacle` class?

Comment: I have 4 instances of the Obstacle class that just decrease in y-value until they leave the screen and then get repositioned again. I'm checking collision/if the player passes etc for every one of them.

Comment: Okay. So having the `obstacle` go off screen and then `score++` may not keep the score correct. Can you try, adding an `else` to `bird.pos > obstacle.pos` and in it set `over = true`. This way, if the bird is NOT over the obstacle, then `over` will be reset. That is the only other idea I have.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. I added an `else` after the `if(!over)` statement (which I think is what you meant) but it has the same result as it has in my post.

Comment: I meant the one above that. `if (bird.getPosition().y > obstacle.getPosLeft().y) {
  if (!over) {
    over = true;
    score++;
  } else{ over = true; }`

Comment: That results in no points at all because `over` is true all the time, meaning it always thinks the player is above the obstacles and unable to give any points because it only gives points if `over` is `false`.

Comment: Sorry, without more code those are the only ideas I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a "obstacle.over" boolean so that each has its own state.

Comment: Ohh yes, I totally forgot that each obstacle has its own variables. Stupid me. Thanks a lot.